# Bootstrap 5 Responsive Text and Alignment

Tags: html, css, responsive, bootstrap-5, text-styling

I want to make my div element centered but the text alignment is on the left.
Code:

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1><strong>Hello, what we can do for you?</strong></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I tried to put text-center in the container and put text-align left for col class, but the thing is my div element and the text both centered. I can't configure how to make the text alignment to the left.
Failed attempt:
HTML

```
 <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1><strong>Hello, what we can do for you?</strong></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col{text-align:left;}
```

Comment: Do you want to make your text in center or left?

Answer (score 0):

**TEXT WITH CENTER ALIGN**

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1><strong>Hello, what we can do for you?</strong></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TEXT WITH LEFT ALIGN**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1><strong>Hello, what we can do for you?</strong></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```